# refresh Iframe without affecting parent page without iframe id

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am using 2 Iframe in my index page. If any action is preferred from any Iframe, it must reload that Iframe alone. But it overrides my index page as one of the Iframe URL. Can any one help me to fix this issue.

My expected result is working in Chrome but it not working in Internet explorer

Note: Iframe id and name generated automatically

I used the below command to refresh the Iframe window

`window.location.reload(true)`

`window.top.location.reload(true)`

[screen reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mcrkm.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Try to reload the specific Iframe element because you're probably reloading the whole page (window) right now.

1- First you must take the name for each Iframe with the `name` attribute.

2- Later try to use the javascript function `document.getElementsByName("IframeName")` to retrieve the specific Iframe. After that you can take the resulting object (the Iframe) to apply the changes you need (to change the `src` attribute).

**IMPORTANT:** Remember that iframes are neither supported by every browsers nor HTML5.

Hope it helps you...

Comment: i request you to provide some more in details

Comment: Can you please, share your code for a better explanation?